# After readline from txt in VBA, I used Trim to erase the extra space. then I got lines with weird first character which I don't know what it is?

Tags: vba, ascii

I loaded data from a txt file, the data are following:

```
  //&policy->GMIB_Payout_Period,    
  &policy->ScenNum,     
  //&policy->GMIB_Payout_Period,

' create a strLine as collection to store each line
Dim str As String
Dim strLine As New Collection
Do Until fileStream.AtEndOfStream
    str = fileStream.ReadLine
    str = Trim(str) ' erase the extra space
    strLine.Add str
Loop

fileStream.Close
```

I used the strLine to store the strings, and then I created the another collection which I use to as a mark based on the different forms of the data. 
I want to mark the data as -1 when it started with // such as line 1 and 3. Here is the code:

```
Dim temp As Variant
Dim i As Variant
Dim hash As New Collection
For Each i In strLine
    If i = "" Then
        hash.Add 0
    ElseIf Left(i, 2) = "//" Then
        hash.Add -1
    Else
        temp = Split(i, ",")
        If InStr(i, "//") <> 0 Then
            hash.Add UBound(temp) - LBound(temp) - 1
        Else
            hash.Add UBound(temp) - LBound(temp)
        End If
    End If
Next i
```

As a result, the line 1 as I expected was marked as -1, but line 3 not.

Then I used

```
Debug.print Left(strLine(3),1) ' the result looked like a space
```

Then I used

```
If Left(strLine(3), 1) = " " Then
    Debug.Print 1
Else
    Debug.Print 0
End If
```

The result is 1 which means it's not a space.

So, I want to ask what's the first character is? and why the line 1 is as it supposed be, but the line 3 is different story?

Comment: You can use `MsgBox ASC(Left(strLine(3), 1))` to see the Ascii code for it. What number does that give you?

Comment: Hi, I checked it out. It's a tab and I used 'replace(str, chr(9),"")' to replace it. Thanks!